# Read Object with multiple colon in key in php

Tags: php, json

I have object something like below structure.

Note multiple colons in key. How can I read this in php.
I want to read access_token and other same level data.
But can't get it working due to multiple colons in key.

```
__PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
(
    [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => GoogleGAL_Client
    [auth:GoogleGAL_Client:private] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
        (
            [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => GoogleGAL_Auth_OAuth2
            [assertionCredentials:GoogleGAL_Auth_OAuth2:private] => 
            [state:GoogleGAL_Auth_OAuth2:private] => 
            [token:GoogleGAL_Auth_OAuth2:private] => Array
                (
                    [access_token] => ashfkahsfk
                    [token_type] => Bearer
                    [expires_in] => 3598
                    [id_token] => edjkajdl
                    [created] => 1432752375
                )
```

Comment: What is the relation with json? And how are you trying to access your properties? Note that if this is a real object, you cannot access the private properties without some kind of getter method.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I mean object.

Comment: I have this object in variable but can't read it.

Comment: try access elements by $obj->element?

Comment: @ Ali Torabi It's basic method. Already tried. Also tried some other methods. but didn't worked.

Comment: It's a private property, so no method to return it => no access.

Comment: Furthermore the inner object (GoogleGAL_Client) is also private.

Comment: @LuckyBurger Yes right. I think I will have to do some other way to read token.